# SQL Server 2008R2 to SQL Server 2012 Install

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, installation

I'm trying to upgrade one of my SQL servers from 2008R2 to 2012 and I'm getting an error popup within a couple of seconds from starting the setup

The Error is

> ### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> `SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>   There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting UIMODE.
>   Error code 0x85640002.For help, click:http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0xC6B69F4C%25400xDC80C325`

The Microsoft help link is http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0xC6B69F4C%25400xDC80C325

I've spent a good amount of time searching for this error on google and stackoverflow to no avail. I've only found errors that are kind of like it that have to do with this

> There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting ALLINSTANCES

What I've tried.

- I ran a dotnet repair tool from Microsoft
- Ran as Admin/From a different account
- Installing from a cmd prompt using `uimode=Normal action=Install`
  and `uimode=autoadvance action=install`.
- Unzipping ISO to C: drive and ran install from there.
- Re-downloaded the ISO to see if it was a corrupt download.
- Downloaded SQL Server 2012 SP2 installer.

All of these have failed to get past this error. The below link is from the install log located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log`

Install Log http://pastebin.com/Z71VSgg9

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You've eliminated this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22088932/error-while-trying-to-upgrade-sql-server-2008-sp2-to-sql-server-2012-there-wa

Comment: Yup I've eliminated this